# How do I make nginx running as a docker service accessible from the host?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-network

Not for production. I was able to run nginx in a container like so:

```
# docker run --rm -itp 4000:80 nginx
# curl localhost:4000
<outputs welcome page>
```

But with docker compose it doesn't work:

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:stable
    ports:
      - "4001:80"
```

Then,

```
# docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml s1
# curl localhost:4001
<hangs>
```

But it works this way:

```
# curl DOCKER0_IP:4001
```

or

```
# curl DOCKER_GWBRIDGE:4001
```

I'm running Arch Linux.

`docker stack ls`:

```
NAME                SERVICES            ORCHESTRATOR
s1                  1                   Swarm
```

`docker stack ps s1`:

```
ID                  NAME                IMAGE               NODE                DESIRED STATE       CURRENT STATE            ERROR               PORTS
s9en6oyoj338        s1_nginx.1          nginx:stable        yuri                Running             Running 13 seconds ago
```

`pacman -Qs docker | sed 'n;d'`:

```
local/docker 1:18.09.0-2
```

`docker service ls`:

```
ID                  NAME                MODE                REPLICAS            IMAGE               PORTS
710d1lrq7phh        s1_nginx            replicated          1/1                 nginx:stable        *:4001->80/tcp
```

Comment: @Siyu I believe I'm running the latest version, see `pacman` output in the question. Can't you reproduce? What version are *you* running?

Comment: right, I meant to ask the output of  `docker service ls`. Can't reproduce, same version

Comment: @Siyu It works via `docker0` and `docker_gwbridge` interfaces. I guess your OS makes `docker0` automatically available. What's your OS? Can you show `iptables-save` output?

Comment: ubuntu 18.04. it shows lots of -A Forward and post routing

Comment: Any update on this? I have landed into this exact problem on Arch Linux

Comment: @GaganTK The update is probably as follows. You're not supposed to run Docker Swarm locally. Use docker-compose instead. But if you do (use Docker Swarm), it won't be accessible via `localhost`.